# :Contains doesnt work with a variable instead of just text

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css

Hello everyone I have a search bar and some bootstrap cards, what I want to do is to have all the cards with display none, but once I'm typing on search bar (keyup), I want to display only the cards that contain the same word. I'm feeling stuck so some help or any advice would be awesome. Thanks.

Example

```js
$("#search_value").keyup(function() {
  let searchInputValue = $("#search_value").val();
  $("div.card-body h4.card-title:contains('" + searchInputValue + "')").css("display", "flex");
})
```

```css
div.card-body h4.card-title {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form action="">
  <input id="search_value" type="text" class="form-control" name="search_articles" placeholder="Search...">
  <button class="search-icon"><img src="./search-icon.png" alt=""></button> </form>

<div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title pt-3 pb-3"><a href="./article-template.html"> article about videogames</a></h4>
  <p class="card-text text-muted hide-card-text-mobile">In our last few articles...</p>
</div>
```

Contains works if I use a string but not if I use a variable..

Comment: You need to hide all the items that don't match the selector. Otherwise, they'll keep showing even when you change the input.

Comment: It works above. If you type `video` you see the title.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to be an escape problems.

It's working using bracket

```js
$("#search_value").keyup(function() {
  let searchInputValue = $(this).val();
  let titleContain = $(`div.card-body h4.card-title:contains('${searchInputValue}')`);
  console.log(searchInputValue)
  if (searchInputValue.length > 3)
    titleContain.css("display", "flex");
  else
    titleContain.css("display", "none");
})
```

```css
div.card-body h4.card-title {
  display: none;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input id="search_value" type="text" class="form-control" name="search_articles" placeholder="Search...">
<button class="search-icon"><img src="./search-icon.png" alt=""></button> </form>

<div class="card-body">
  <h4 class="card-title pt-3 pb-3"><a href="./article-template.html"> article about videogames</a></h4>
  <p class="card-text text-muted hide-card-text-mobile">In our last few articles...</p>
</div>
```